Why do the CTEs work different from the Subqueries in MySQL?
I try deleting all the goods, whose type_name starts with D.
Let's say I wanna delete goods from the types of dentistry, delicacies, darts_game.
So I check whether the type is in the list d_goods_ids (type is a FK of good_type_id).
WITH d_goods_ids AS (SELECT good_type_id FROM GoodTypes 
                 WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%")

DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN d_goods_ids;

SELECT * FROM Goods;

But MySQL raises an error:
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd_goods_ids; SELECT * FROM Goods' at line 5

Whereas if I use a subquery, everything works perfectly:
DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN (SELECT good_type_id FROM GoodTypes 
               WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%");

SELECT * FROM Goods;

Shouldn't both variants work the same in this context?

A cte is a subquery.

You can reference a CTE in a subquery, but not like you are trying to do it.
WITH d_goods_ids AS (SELECT good_type_id FROM GoodTypes
                 WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%")

DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN (SELECT good_type_id FROM d_goods_ids);

In this example, the CTE is in a subquery, referenced in a FROM clause as if it's a table name.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/with.html says:

cte_name names a single common table expression and can be used as a table reference in the statement containing the WITH clause.

(bold emphasis is mine)
So you can use a CTE where you would otherwise use a table reference.
Another way of thinking about the syntax is that you can't substitute an isolated table name for a subquery.
In other words, the following example is not a valid IN predicate, for the same reason using a CTE in that place is not valid:
DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN GoodTypes;


Another way to properly use the CTE in the DELETE can look like this
WITH d_goods_ids AS (
  SELECT good_type_id
  FROM GoodTypes
  WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%"
)

DELETE Goods
FROM Goods
JOIN d_goods_ids ON d_goods_ids.good_type_id = Goods.type;


DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN (SELECT good_type_id FROM GoodTypes 
               WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%");

The subquery in the WHERE IN clause produces a set of values which can be used in the expression.
WITH d_goods_ids AS (SELECT good_type_id FROM GoodTypes 
                 WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%")
DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN d_goods_ids;

The CTE query produces a table which cannot be used in the expression. You'd specify one definite column which should be used, but you cannot do this because this table is not mentioned in the data source (FROM) clause.
The fact that there is only one column in this table in your particular query doesn't affect anything.
PS. If your MySQL is 8.0.19 or newer then you may use
WITH d_goods_ids AS (SELECT good_type_id FROM GoodTypes 
                 WHERE GoodTypes.good_type_name LIKE "d%")
DELETE FROM Goods
WHERE type IN (TABLE d_goods_ids);

In this case the fact that the CTE table consists from only one column produces synthactically correct code. But this is hidden sub-select nevertheless and not direct table access.
